# What to do with [dim]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [dim](/questions/tagged/dim) tag is used for a variety of items, which mainly consist of one of the following:

- the literal English definition of the word "dim"
- the VB.NET keyword `dim`

There is also one question about an obscure name for some proprietary item/feature I have no idea about. This tag has no excerpt, nor any tag wiki. What should we do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of variable declaration, [variable-declaration](/questions/tagged/variable-declaration) *might* be appropriate, but it’s probably unnecessary. In the literal definition, [screen](/questions/tagged/screen) or [brightness](/questions/tagged/brightness) should be used. I’ve done the appropriate retagging… mostly (all [dim](/questions/tagged/dim)s on a [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) question were just removed).

I don’t think any synonyms need to be created.